# A different way to version api output with laravel?

Tags: laravel, api, versioning

I'm about to ...

1. extend my App/Orm/MyModel.php with Http/Json/V1/MyModel.php so I can keep the $appends, $hides, toArray() neatly tucked away in a V1
2. namespace and prefix some routing for V1
3. probably do some custom resolvers for route model binding

And I'm thinking ... really?  They haven't built this in... what am I missing here?  There's gotta be a quick, turn-key for this.  I'm interested in knowing how other people are doing this, so please chime in.

Comment: Are you in the need of v2 already? Most likely you won't pass by v1, so just stick with non-versioned API and when times come you can refactor.

Comment: @Kyslik just planning ahead.

Comment: Wasting your time, imagine you have v1 and its doing fine; now you decide to develop v2; whats the process? You need to copy "all the files" and change the namespace and some more stuff above (middleware / service providers / routes) and now you can start working with v2. Can't you do that later when its actually needed? v1 will have no special namespace and v2 will have thats it.

Comment: @Kyslik  This is just for output versioning.

Comment: I will come here in a year and ask you if you made it through *v1* (whatever that means) :). Good luck!

Comment: @Kyslik  That would be epically hilarious if you actually checked in next year - lol.  And epically sad if I find myself still sitting in this same spot tapping away at a keyboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Try Resources instead of Models

Have a look at resources:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources

And add your logic to resources so that you display different versions of a model depending on the API version. You can still make use of `$appends` and `$hidden`.

With this approach we return a Resource of a model rather than the model itself.

Here is an example of a UserResource for different API versions:

```
class UserResource extends JsonResource
{
    private $apiVersion;

    public function __construct($resource, int $apiVersion = 2) {
        $this->apiVersion = $apiVersion; // OPTION 1: Pass API version in the constructor
        parent::__construct($resource);
    }

    public function toArray($request): array
    {
        // OPTION 2: Get API version in the request (ideally header)
        // $apiVersion = $request->header('x-api-version', 2);

        /** @var User $user */
        $user = $this->resource;

        return [
            'type' => 'user',
            'id' => $user->id,
            $this->mergeWhen($this->apiVersion < 2, [
                'name' => "{$user->first_name} {$user->last_name}",
            ], [
                'name' => [
                    'first' => $user->first_name,
                    'last' => $user->last_name
                ],
            ]),
            'score' => $user->score,
        ];
    }
}
```

The you can call:

```
$user = User::find(5);
return new UserResource($user);
```

If you need a different connection you can do:

```
$user = User::on('second_db_connection')->find(5);
```

So V1 API gets:

```
{
    id: 5,
    name: "John Smith",
    score: 5
}
```

and V2 API gets:

```
{
    id: 5,
    name: {
         first: "John",
         last: "Smith",
    },
    score: 5
}
```

Now if later you wanted to rename score to points in your DB, and in V3 of your API you also wanted to change your JSON output, but maintain backwards compatibility you can do:

```
   $this->mergeWhen($this->apiVersion < 3, [
       'score' => $user->points,    
   ], [
       'points' => $user->points,
   ])
```

### Prefix routes

You can easily prefix routes as mentioned here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-group-prefixes

```
Route::prefix('v1')->group(function () {
    Route::get('users', function () {
        // ...
    });
});
```

### Explicit Route Model Binding

To do custom route model bindings have a look at: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-model-binding

e.g.

```
Route::bind('user', function ($value) {
    return App\User::where('name', $value)->first() ?? abort(404); // your customer logic
});
```

Comment: Eloquent resource is on the right track, thanks.  Looks pretty  limited, but maybe sometimes limits are a good thing.  Cheers!

Comment: @TarekAdam Please mark this answer as correct if it solved your problem

Comment: Still looking into the issue.

Comment: Took another look, but I'm just not seeing the benefit ~ other than ... it's light.  On the drawback side, I can't set a connection - and that's a deal breaker since the Json output namespaced models will be read from slaves.

Comment: What do you mean you cannot see a connection and "the JSON output namespaces models will be read from slaves"? I'm really confused by what you mean by that.

Comment: "can't set a connection" - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985472/change-database-connection-in-laravel-model

Comment: So you want to use a different database connection depending on which API version you are using. This is an unusual requirement to change your database connection just because your using a different API version. It annoys me when other people asks me this question, but I have to ask, Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Would it be possible to give more context in question to describe your database connection requirements, as this is not mentioned anywhere.

Comment: Ya, awesome.  Thanks for your interest!!  https://s3.amazonaws.com/tarekadam/random/Screen+Shot+2018-11-22+at+11.56.13+AM.png

Comment: The code shown does not seem to describe your database connection requirements. What is it that you need to do? Do you want a different database connection for each API version and why?

Comment: Some time before it goes live - I'll add protected $connection = 'some_slave'; to the V1/Lander.php class

Comment: I don't think it will be too tough to maintain, and has so many benefits over Resource.  Obviously now that you've seen it -  you know I'm not code-god - so I could be totally missing the point.

Comment: So if I understand this, you want to use a different database connection depending if your on production or local

Comment: No, it's all for prod.  Different namespaces using different connections because the Json namespace will only ever read.

Comment: So when exactly do you want a different connection. Is it for different API versions?

Comment: In config/database.php I'm supposed to have separate connections for the default read and default write, but for the public api it's a different connection again.

Comment: 1 connection split by read and write, then another connection for read to json

Comment: Got it. You can specify different connections for read/ write by editing your database config file as mentioned here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database#read-and-write-connections

Comment: Appreciate the help.  I shouldn't eat anymore of your time.  Cheers.

Comment: Resource is just a wrapper around a model. You don't need to set a connection on a resource. You first fetch your models and pass your models to the resource so it formats it in the way you want. See my updated answer to how resources work.

Comment: Updated answer to include how to do another connection

Comment: Any idea for resource collection? This approach doesn't work for resource collection.