# Polymorphism across databases using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphism

So I'm using Laravel's built in morph methods to create a simple system where you are able to "like" any given model instance. It is working as expected when both the "likes" and "model" tables are in the same db. I'm running into an issue though when I'm trying to set up a relation on a model where the table is in a different db. Even when I set the db connection on the Likes model it ignores this whenever I call `withCount('likes')`.  I keep getting an error saying that the `model.likes doesn't exist` - which of course it doesn't.  It's on a different table. Is there a way to always force the `morphMany` or `morphTo` methods to target a specific database?

As an update - the actual "like" is being stored properly - but when calling the `withCount('likes')` method it's not honoring the connection property.

Comment: you can specify your database connection in your eloquent model : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985472/change-database-connection-in-laravel-model

Comment: As I stated in the question - I already have the connection set on the Likes model. It seems to be getting ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Well bummer.  Just realized that the `withCount` method doesn't support eager loading like `with` does currently.

[Note here on github](https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/593)