# how to change database conection and tabel in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

i have two database connections. I need to search for both of them.
if the User doesn't exist in the first table and connection, fetch from the second first table and connection.

```
$customer = User::find($id);
if (!$customer) {
  // how to get second fetch connection
}
```

tables and connections information:

first:

table = users

connection = mysql_1

second:

table = old_users

connection = mysql_2

Comment: check this question, hope it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985472/change-database-connection-in-laravel-model

Comment: Have you set connection for the Databased

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution

```
$customer = User::find($id);
if (!$customer) {
    $customer = User::on('other')->find($id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your tables are the same, and are just in different connections.

First set up another connection in your database config file if you haven't already done so. You will use the array key to access it.

[image]

Then you can do:

```
$customer = User::find($id);
if (!$customer) {
    $customer = User::on('automations')->find($id);
}
```

`automations` can be whatever you want, so long as it matches your configuration file. This config is just an example from my database config file.